# Pandas float in an expanding window cannot be coerced

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have this array I make into a dataframe:

```
a = np.array([1,20,200,10.0])
df = pd.DataFrame({"a" :a})
>>> df
       a
0    1.0
1   20.0
2  200.0
3   10.0
```

I try to make an expanding window over this, and even the most minimal example fails:

```
>>> df.a.expanding(2).apply(lambda x: x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

Why isn't this clearly float value being treated like a float?  It's a float:

```
>>> df.a.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

Why is it failing to be coerced? To what?  Same for rolling:

```
>>> df.a.rolling(2).apply(lambda x: x)
    raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

Comment: `rolling` or `expanding` expects a Scalar, but you are passing a `pd.Series` by `lambda x:x`.

Comment: The issue is as follows: `expanding` and `rolling` operations _must_ produce a single numeric value. No other dtypes are supported natively. Here you're returning a collection (`Series`) which cannot be converted to an acceptable type. Note the return must be a _numeric_ scalar. `df.a.expanding(2).apply(lambda x: 'a')` would produce an error as well. (`TypeError: must be real number, not str`)